# Doing Knex "the Koa2 way"

Tags: node.js, knex.js, koa2

In [the docs for Application](http://koajs.com/#application) there's a note on using `context` to expose widely used properties in `ctx`:

> For example, to add a reference to your database from ctx:
>
> ```
> app.context.db = db();
>
> app.use(async ctx => {
>   console.log(ctx.db);
> });
> ```

However, it also notes that relying more on `ctx` "could be considered an anti-pattern". Fair enough.

Then we have [koa-knex-realworld-example](https://github.com/gothinkster/koa-knex-realworld-example/blob/master/src/middleware/db-middleware.js) which suggests something like this:

> ```
> module.exports = function (app) {
>   // ...
>
>   const db = require('knex')(config.db)
>   app.db = db
>
>   // ...
>
>   return async function (ctx, next) {
>     if (ctx.app.migration && promise) {
>       await promise
>     }
>
>     return next()
>   }
> }
> ```

And passes the `app` instance to the middleware:

> ```
> app.use(db(app))
> ```

That feels strange to me. Having to pass `app` to its own middleware seems a little backwards, but maybe it's a known Koa pattern?

Finally, we have [koa-knex](https://github.com/tjwebb/koa-knex-middleware) which exposes `knex` as `this.knex` in  middleware further down the stack:

> ```
> app.use(_.get('/:userid', function *(userid) {
>   this.body = {
>     profile: yield this.knex('users').where('id', userid);
>   };
> });
> ```

That one's a bit dated (generators, which are fine but not the default API for Koa anymore) and chucks Knex in `global`:

> ```
> global.__knex || (global.__knex = Knex.initialize({
>   // ...
> }));
> this.knex = global.__knex;
>
> yield next;
> ```

**What's the alternative?**

In summary, I think I'm pretty comfortable putting a reference to Knex in the context, and I don't think I'll be tempted to pollute it with too much else. However, if I wanted an alternative, is there a middleware approach to making Knex available in Koa2 that is preferable to the above options?

Comment: You might want to consider `require`ing knex in route handlers files. For example, in my applications I usually create `knex.js` file with `module.exports = require('knex')(/*...config...*/)` and then use it in application like `require('./path/to/local/knex')`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, that's certainly another possibility. I think I'd rather have Knex available by the time I get to a route, as I suspect it makes for a better testing story (easier to stub/mock) than if it's required in each handler.

Comment: You could use coockoo's approach but just create a middleware that attaches it to the context. I think its best to initialize knex once. If you initialize it on each request, you might run out of connections (each instance of knex will use up to 10 connections by default)